# actionbarsherlock fragments: view not completely loaded in onActivityCreated() or onStart()

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

In Activity.onStart() and Fragment1.onActivityCreated() and Fragment1.onStart() methods my complete activity view layout is not fully loaded.

In onActivityCreated() none of the view is loaded (I have several fragments with up to 20 elements on each).  findViewById(R.id.somefield) returns null.

In onStart() the first fragment view is accessible but none of the other fragments.

If I don't try accessing any view components at all in any of these methods and just let the application start and then try accessing the view in an onclick listener the entire view on all fragments is then accessible (I use setOffscreenPageLimit).

Something seems strange about the activity-fragment lifecycle as documented.

I have noticed some other people posting about trouble accessing view components when using fragments as well.

Is there some way to test for when the entire view is fully loaded?

UPDATE: moving the view accesses into onActivityCreated() in the furthest indexed fragment seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the log that explains why I had to move the accesses into the last fragment's onActivityCreated:

```
V/MyApp( 7269): Activity: onCreate:
V/MyApp( 7269): Activity: onStart:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment1: onCreateView:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment1: onActivityCreated:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment1: onStart:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment2: onCreateView:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment2: onActivityCreated:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment2: onStart:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment3: onCreateView:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment3: onActivityCreated:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment3: onStart:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment4: onCreateView:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment4: onActivityCreated:
V/MyApp( 7269): Fragment4: onStart:
```

The activity view is not complete until the last fragment lifecycle methods are called.